# C# display generic array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C# generic and I cannot seem to be able to display elements inside the array.  When i debug the code, I could see the elements if I expand the node employee.  However when I try to display it, it just prints out the class name instead of actual elements.  Please look below.

```
public class PrintArray<T>
{
    public void OutputGeneric(T[] employee)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < employee.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n" + employee[i]);//I can't access to FullName and Salary
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    private string Name;
    private int Income;

    public string FullName
    {
        set { Name = value;}
        get { return Name; }
    }

    public int Salary
    {
        set { Income = value; }
        get { return Income; }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintArray<Employee> pa = new PrintArray<Employee>();

        Console.Write("\n\Employee: ");
        Employee[] customArray = new Employee[3];
        customArray[0] = new Employee()
        {
            FullName = "John Doe",
            Salary = 100000
        };
        customArray[1] = new Employee()
        {
            FullName = "Mary Jane",
            Salary = 50000
        };
        customArray[2] = new Employee()
        {
            FullName = "Tyler Smith",
            Salary = 80000
        };

        pa.OutputGeneric(customArray);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access `FullName` or `Salary` because `T` could be anything... i.e. `string` , `int`, `StringBuilder`, `Person`, `Car` etc.... either use a `Employee[]` or look into constraints on type parameters.

Comment: If you want the method to be truly generic, then you will only have access to members of the common base class, `object` (such as `ToString()`) when using `T`. Adding [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) on `T` will give you access to properties and methods based on the specified constraint. If you constrain `T` to `Employee`, you will have access to the `Employee` members, but then the method is not very generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override ToString in your Employee class (and similarly for any other class you want to use in `PrintArray`).

```
public class Employee
{
    private string Name;
    private int Income;

    public string FullName
    {
        set { Name = value;}
        get { return Name; }
    }

    public int Salary
    {
        set { Income = value; }
        get { return Income; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}, Salary: {1}", Name, Salary);
    }
}
```

Comment: By allowing them to do this for any class they want to use, as opposed to constraining a generic class to use one specific class (or classes derived from it)

Comment: @Phil M - You beat me to it.  This is absolutely the "best" reply.

Comment: Maybe you should let the OP decide what he's looking for. He may be trying to learn Generics, but his question simply states he wants to be able to print the Employee correctly. Stop accusing people trying to help of being 'unfriendly' or unwelcoming, just because you don't agree on what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of achieving what you were originally looking for while still having the generic `PrintArray` class and method, you can get close to it by defining a delegate parameter that you can use to specify which properties will be printed:

```
public void OutputGeneric(T[] employee, Func<T, dynamic> selector)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < employee.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("\n" + selector(employee[i]));//I still can't access to FullName and Salary
    }
}
```

Calling this method would then look like:

```
pa.OutputGeneric(customArray, x => new { x.FullName, x.Salary });
```

Providing output as:

[image: Output]

Or you could format the output with something like:

```
pa.OutputGeneric(customArray, x => $"{x.FullName} makes ${x.Salary}");
```

Which creates the output as:

[image: FormattedOutput]

Answer (score -1):

`PrintArray` should not be a class. you must override `ToString` of `Employee` class.

```
public class Employee
{
    private string Name;
    private int Income;

    public string FullName
    {
        set { Name = value;}
        get { return Name; }
    }

    public int Salary
    {
        set { Income = value; }
        get { return Income; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Employee Name: {0}, Salary: {1}", Name, Salary);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee[] customArray = new Employee[3];
    customArray[0] = new Employee()
    {
        FullName = "John Doe",
        Salary = 100000
    };
    customArray[1] = new Employee()
    {
        FullName = "Mary Jane",
        Salary = 50000
    };
    customArray[2] = new Employee()
    {
        FullName = "Tyler Smith",
        Salary = 80000
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < employee.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(employee[i].ToString() + "\n");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: thanks.  I can display elements without using generic class but i want to learn generic that is why I create print function.

Comment: @Phil Try this youtube video about generics i am watching as well :) https://youtu.be/l6s7AvZx5j8